# Error while compile java using MVN

Tags: java, android, macos, maven

I would like to compile and build a jar file from https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/archive/spongy-master.zip (SpongeCastle library)

However, when I tried to test MVN, the MVN shows following error
(JDK 1.6.0_37, Maven 3.0.4, Mac OSX snowleopard)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) on project scpg-jdk15on: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/Lara/Desktop/BlowFish/spongycastle-spongy-master/scpg-jdk15on/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :scpg-jdk15on
```

How can I solve the error?

Comment: did you read the error message ?

Comment: And what is unclear to you in the message?

Comment: the artifact seems to be for jdk 1.5 and you are using jdk 1.6 ... maybe the cause of the issue ? look into /Users/Lara/Desktop/BlowFish/spongycastle-spongy-master/scpg-jdk15on/target/surefire-reports

Comment: all errors contain [Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider SC] what this mean?, how can I authenticate the provider SC?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a unit test named "default-test" that is failing and is preventing maven from building the jar. You can either investigate and fix the cause of the failing test, or you can try to build the jar without running tests using:

```
 mvn install -DskipTests
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comments, it's maybe a problem with your jdk version, but maybe something else...

I suggest you to read this : http://www.randombugs.com/java/javalangsecurityexception-jce-authenticate-provider-bc.html

I think it will help you identifying/solving your issue.